# Expressing statement with predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Given interpretation ℕ with signature ⟨0, 1; +, ·; =⟩, I need to express statement using predicates: $x$ is not divisible by any prime smaller than $y$

Comment: I don't know how to start. I edited my post to remove three answers

Comment: Thanks for doing so, Kuu Vab.

Comment: How much are you able to do yourself?  Are you able to write any statements using predicate logic?  Even if you can't write this one, show us your attempt, or some statements that you could write.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Zeroth: How do we write out "w is larger than y"? Let $w > y$ be this formula.

First: How do we write "w divides x"? Let $d(w,x)$ be this formula.

Second: How do we say "w is prime"? - Let $P(w)$ be this formula.

Third: Notice that "$x$ is not divisible by an prime smaller than $y$" is equivalent to saying that "every prime which divides $x$ is greater than or equal to $y$". Hence we can conclude that the formula looks as follows:  $$(\forall w) ( [d(w,x) \wedge P(w)] \to [(w > y) \vee (w =y)])$$

I've left it to you to write out $d(w,x)$, $P(w)$, and $w > y$.

Comment: w is larger than y: ∃z(w - z = y & ¬(z = 0)); w divides x: ∃z(w = x · z) & ¬(x = 0); w is prime: ∀y∀z(w = y · z → y = 1 ∨ z = 1) & ¬(w = 1). Are these correct? I don't know how to format text correctly

Comment: @KuuVab: Remember, you don't have subtraction in your language.

Comment: ∃z(w = z + y & ¬(z = 0)) then?

Comment: @KuuVab: Yes, those look good, except in your definition of "w divides x", why do you make it so that $\neg (x = 0)$?

Comment: @KuuVab: I would write $w$ divides $x$ as $(\exists z)( w \cdot z = x \wedge w \neq 0)$